# If I refuse to divorce my wife, can the Shari'ah Council divorce us against my will?

Tags: sharia, talaq

My local mosque asked me and my wife to go there to discuss if a reconciliation between was possible. I said I wanted to give our marriage another chance, but my wife said she wanted a divorce. Next week, I am invited to attend another session, but this time to give her a divorce. I want to know if I refuse to give my wife a divorce, can she automatically receive it from the Shari'ah Council?

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [how to ask a question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and take a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My husband has refused divorce. Can I go to court to seek for divorce?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28148/my-husband-has-refused-divorce-can-i-go-to-court-to-seek-for-divorce)

Comment: @PointlessSpike the duplicate doesn't offer an accepted answer!

Comment: That's a separate issue. It's a bad idea to have half a dozen questions for the same thing just because they don't get answered.

Comment: @PointlessSpike also note that what you presented as a dupilcate is basically a different question, as it asks from a  diffferent perspective. And without further knowledge of what exactly happened this question is not answerable (as we don't know whether it is about faskh, khula' or a divorece initaiated by the wife)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it requires much more detailed information to be answerable. We don't know what the status of this 'Sharaiah Council' is ... does it have a mufti & jurisdiction from an Islamic government? Then it would depend on whether it is a case of *fask* or a *khul*. Then if it is *khul*, it would depend on the *madhab* and the reason behind it as some allow the *qadi* to force the husband to give a *khul* when the reasons behind it are severe enough.

Comment: And duplicate answer has `Error 404' now what? this is one of weakness of this site.